# Can I use MAMP with Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

Installed Visual Studio for Mac. Can I use MAMP, since SQL Server is not available for mac?

Comment: are you doing c# or php development?

Comment: trying c# development.

Comment: as per my answer, the only useful bit of MAMP will be the MySql instance it provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP will provide a MySql instance that you could connect to from your application.

MAMP will also run an apache web server that will run PHP applications. You could use Visual Studio Code to edit these PHP files.

The two are totally unrelated, however.